# Creating an Android App which records data as a pie chart

Tags: software-recommendation, information-graphics

Hey this might be a bit of a tricky one!

I have designed the wireframes for an application which will work out expenditures on a weekly monthly and yearly basis.

The first screen is for input, with 4 fields:

1. A simple text box to input the name for the item bought/bills.
2. A drop-down box to pick from categories to find the one that best describes the product.
3. A text box which the price of the product is entered.
4. Something to determine whether the data input is an expenditure or income.

I have then designed the next screen to be a list of every item the user has entered.  The user can view weekly, monthly and yearly results.

The information will be then be broken-down into the different categories and displayed with pie charts showing weekly, monthly, and yearly results.

I have all the details to make the app in the visual style that I want, but I feel as a graphic designer the next step is above me!

If anyone as any idea of what software to use and how to code it help would be much appreciated as this app has to be made as an university project.

Comment: Welcome to GD.  As it stands, your question may be closed for being too broad.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: [Google's code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html) might get you started. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement something like [this](http://www.liquidx.net/canvasgraphjs/), jQuery Pie Chart, you would use PHP or some similar web technology for this. If you do, I'm figuring you'll need to park it somewhere on the internet. The idea is to get the variables the user sets and insert them into the respective spots in the source.

I have seen Java and ASP.net sources, some are paid, others are free, though I'm a graphic designer, not a programmer.

It it possible with other languages